# python Regex to match sentences which has n words

Tags: python, regex

Im looking for a python regex which matches sentences with 3 words before a string.

for example say i have sentence "this is the test" i want to match this one and only if there are any 3 words before the string test.

```
re.match(r'(\d\w+\d){3}test', "this is the test")
```

thought the above sentence would work but didnt work.

Comment: What are you using `\d` to indicate?

Comment: What about `re.match(r'(\w+\s){3}test', 'this is the test')`?

Comment: word boundry...thought with \d wrapped around it will treat each set of char as a word...@mohammad...thanks works well.

Comment: dont really see why i got downvoted...

Comment: word boundary is `\b` (for boundary).  `\d` is digits, aka `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want to **match** strings with 3 words, separated by whitespace(s) followed by 'test': `(\b){3}test`
- If you want to **extract** first 3 words, separated by whitespace(s) followed by 'test': `(\w+\s+){3}test`
- If you want same thing, but want to allow whitespace(s) before the stopword: `(\w+\s+){3}\w?test`
- If you want to do same, but with string **ending** with the stopword: `(\w+\s+){3}\w?test$`